# Convert object to double when using GetValue method

Tags: c#

I want to perform a windows form which act as a unit conversion, like conversion from cm to m, etc.
Basically, my main codes are like this:
first binding data to drop down list

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>();
myList.Add("Inch");
DropDownList1.DataSource = myList;
DropDownList1.DataBind();

Int32 index1 = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
Int32 index2 = DropDownList2.SelectedIndex;
Double [,] key = new Double[7,7];
key.SetValue(1, 0, 0);
key.SetValue(1,1,2);
........

Double input_Number = Convert.ToDouble(input.Text);
Double ratio = Convert.ToDouble(key.GetValue(index1, index2));
Double ratio = key.GetValue(index1, index2);
Double result = input_Number*ratio ;  //doesn't appear correct result
Comment.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

It runs ok, but it doesn't perform the function correctly. when i type sth in the inputbox and select cm to m, it doesn't work,always returns the same number. And when i am debugging, i try to see the ratio value,  it still doesn't work.
is it a problem of my conversion from object to double? Because the getvalue method returns an object.

Comment: Side note: "...windows form..." and tag "asp.net" somewhat contradict each other. It probably does not matter much for this question, but in general desktop specific (i.e. WinFroms) and web specific (i.e. asp.net) questions usually need different answers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've got

Double ratio = Convert.ToDouble(key.GetValue(index1, index2));
Double ratio = key.GetValue(index1, index2);

not sure how this going to work. It will not run.

Secondly, i don't think you need do: Double ratio = Convert.ToDouble(key.GetValue(index1, index2));
it should come out with double

Finally, value assignment to your array looks like this:
key.SetValue(1, 0, 0);
key.SetValue(1,1,2);

which is assign value "1" to this 2-D array, so you will get everything times "1", is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your reply. I have found out what's wrong with my code. It's because I wrote in my Dropdown list data bind in page_load. Everytime when I refresh my website, it automatically reset to default, which is the dropdown list item index=0; So it won't appear correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what's wrong with my code. It's because I wrote in my Dropdown list data bind in page_load. Everytime when I refresh my website, it automatically reset to default, which is the dropdown list item index=0; So it won't appear correctly